# Implicit conversions and by-name parameters of target type

Tags: scala

consider this code:

```scala
class DelayedInt(val value: Int) {
  var locked = true
}

object DelayedInt {
  implicit def delayedIntToInt(del: DelayedInt) = {
    if (del.locked) throw new RuntimeException("not yet!")
    del.value
  }
}

object Main {
  var queue: Seq[() => Int] = Seq.empty

  def queueInt(int: => Int): Unit = {
    queue :+= int _
  }

  def printQueue(): Unit =
    for (f <- queue)
      println("int is: " + f.apply())

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val di = new DelayedInt(42)
    // println(5 + di) // throws exception
    queueInt(5 + di) // OK
    queueInt(di) // OK
    di.locked = false
    printQueue()
  }
}
```

The `DelayedInt` class throws an exception upon conversion to int, unless it is explicitly unlocked.

The `println` function must fail, because it invokes the implicit conversion.

`queueInt` function, works fine, seemingly because it uses by-name parameters and the implicit conversion is not invoked until `printQueue`.

What is unclear to me is how does Scala decide when to run the implicit conversion? Especially in case of `queueInt(di)`, it must somehow figure out that the result will be of the right type, without using the implicit conversion.

What are the steps to evaluate this?

Comment: `queueInt(5 + di)` does not seem to throw on my machine. Can you double check that?

Comment: You're right, it makes more sense that it would work fine. I'll modify the question

Comment: Why not a Value Class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is unclear to me is how does Scala decide when to run the implicit conversion?

It doesn't, directly. It just inserts it where required by the expected type, so after that compiler stage your code becomes

```
val di = new DelayedInt(42)
// println(5 + DelayedInt.delayedIntToInt(di)) // throws exception
queueInt(5 + DelayedInt.delayedIntToInt(di)) // OK
queueInt(DelayedInt.delayedIntToInt(di)) // OK
di.locked = false
printQueue()
```

and then the `queueInt` cases behave normally for by-name parameters.

> it must somehow figure out that the result will be of the right type, without using the implicit conversion.

This is of course based on types and doesn't require running anything.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is in both cases, `queueInt(5 + di)` and `queueInt(di)`, implicit conversion should happen before any evaluation takes place. `queueInt` accepts a by-name argument, and then due to `int _` syntax it adds an unapplied *function* to `queue: Seq[() => Int]`, so passed in arguments do not get evaluated after `queueInt` completes. Only when `printQueue()` is called should element functions of `queue` evaluate due to `f.apply()` call.

In the case of `println(5 + di)` the argument is not passed by-name thus after implicit conversion it evaluates *before* it is passed to `println`, hence the throw, but the implicit conversion still happens first, just like for `queueInt` cases.

There does not seem to be anything strange happening here.

Comment: I *think* i got it, but i'm still a little unclear so i left the question up. What confuses me is that Scala knows that `di` is of type `=> Int`, although it ostensibly isn't. But I presume the type system can infer that, without actually running the code?

Comment: `di` is not of type `=> Int`, it is `DelayedInt`. The `=>` construct is not changing the type, it is changing the evaluation strategy of passed-in arguments.